# What is the mass of the following plain?

Tags: calculus, integration

$S={(x,y,z):   x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\geq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\rho(x,y,z)=z$

So I actually solved this problem with cylindrical coordinates, however I imagined it is also easily possible with spherical coordinates.

My attempt with the spherical coordinates was:

$x=\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), y=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), z=\cos(\phi)$

$0\leq\phi\leq \dfrac{2\pi}{3}, 0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\dfrac{2\pi}{3}} \cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) \ d\phi \ d\theta$

The answer is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ But my integral returns a different answer.

Comment: It is really good to see you are finally using mathjax to type in your work :)

Comment: thanks took me some learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that

$x=\cos\theta\sin\phi, y=\sin\theta\sin\phi, z=\cos\phi$

$z\geq\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \implies \cos\phi \geq \sin\phi$

i.e $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$

So the integral should be,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos\phi \sin \phi \ d\phi \ d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$